# Variable Records

Tags: t-sql, query, aggregate

This question keeps coming up at work & collectively we can't think of an easier way to do it than a SQL pivot & huge case statement. So I'm hoping someone might have an idea that could help.

I have a list of records that contains the fields:

- Person_ID
- Status of appointment (DNA / Cancelled / Attended)
- the date of the appointment
- who it was with

Some people have a huge number of records against them, from dates between large time periods eg 2014-2019. Some have a couple of appointments as they've recently been entered as a new person in the application.

I am being asked to see patterns within these appointments. Recent examples are;

- Of all the appointments, did the person not attend 2 or more appointments in a consecutive date period. These aren't necessarily the last 2 appointments (which would have been easier!)
- Of the consecutive appointments not attended, who were they with and what date were they on? How many attendances have they cancelled / attended since those no shows?

As well as this, we're being asked if people have attended appointments 3 times within a rolling 6 month period from 1st January 2014.

Any advice / guidance / tips appreciated!

Thanks,
Ruby

Comment: Could you please add some sample table structure, data with examples. This would help in answering the question.

Comment: Have a read of this and produce us a [mcve] - this will mean we're more likely to help

Comment: You may want to tag your question with the DBMS you use. Based on the "t-sql" tag I suspect it might be SQL Server, but only you would know for sure.